# user, friends, in context of soc. network, what relationship is this

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to implement friend feature to my users, but I need a litlle help.

One `User` can have many `friends`. `Friend` entity cannot exist without `User`.

Knowing that when looking other side relationship does all friend belongs to one user,  or one many friends may point to many users. I'm little bit confused here.

To recapitulate, I have one to many via `User` and what relationship via `Friend`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using C# or Java? I highly doubt you use both. Actually, I don't even know what this question has to do with any of them. Or NHibernate, for that matter.

Comment: you're right, cleaning up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would implement a many-to-many (m-n) relation from User to User. A class named Friend would might be useful to hold some data on your side (one users side).

Including Friend, this might look like:

1 User has N Friends. 1 Friend is simply a "reference" to 1 OTHER User (not the same one as before)

EDIT: Since this model simply includes the Entity Friend as a reference, you might still view it as a many-to-many relationship from User to User.

EDIT2: To rephrase the relationships:

User to Friend: one-to-many. Friend to User: many-to-one (the reverse). And there Friend has a SECOND relationship to User: many-to-one (and of course the reverse one exists as well).

Comment: so if got it, via friend I have one to many,  and many to one via friend side?

Comment: User to Friend: one-to-many. Friend to user: many-to-one (the reverse) and ALSO Friend to (other) user: many-to-one. Friend has two different relationships to User.